# Make exceptions become nulls in Snowflake Java UDF

Tags: sql, jar, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I have a 3rd party JAR that I have made into a UDF as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_DB.MY_SCHEMA.my_udf("FOO" ARRAY)
RETURNS OBJECT
LANGUAGE JAVA
HANDLER = '<proper path>'
IMPORTS = ('@MY_STAGE/path/to/my_jar.jar')
;
```

This works in most cases, but it sometimes returns a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`.

How do I make make SELECT such that all errors become a NULL as the return?

Basically,

```
SELECT NULLIF(my_udf([foo]), IS_ERROR())
```

I can change the UDF CREATE block or the SELECT text, but not the underlying JAR.

Comment: if you have the JAR, you can reverse engineer it, to A) learn what input you are passing that is failing and avoid that, B) fix the Java code to handle valid input it does not handle. C) to be silent in failure. The first is completely valid, the second two can cause concern with regards to licenses in some situations.

Comment: Can you wrap that JAR in your own JAR that calls the 3rd-party code and handles errors by returning null?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a small bit of inline code to wrap the call to the third-party library, such as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_DB.MY_SCHEMA.my_udf("FOO" ARRAY)
RETURNS OBJECT
LANGUAGE JAVA
HANDLER = 'WrapperCode.handler'
IMPORTS = ('@MY_STAGE/path/to/my_jar.jar') AS
'''
import java.util.Map;

class WrapperCode {
  public static Map<String, String> handler(String[] foo) {
    try {
      return com.third_party.library.handler(foo);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
''';
```

Now if the third-party library throws an exception, it will be caught, and the handler method will return `null`. (I'm not sure whether the argument/return type are correct, but you can update them if necessary.)